# IBM Worklight getting error on logcat as unable to read property "APP_SERVICES_URL" of undefined

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

My object is like

> WL.AppProperty = {
>       AIR_ICON_16x16_PATH : "AIR_ICON_16x16_PATH",
>       AIR_ICON_128x128_PATH : "AIR_ICON_128x128_PATH",
>       DOWNLOAD_APP_LINK : "DOWNLOAD_APP_LINK",
>       ENVIRONMENT : "ENVIRONMENT",
>       APP_DISPLAY_NAME : "APP_DISPLAY_NAME",
>       APP_LOGIN_TYPE : "APP_LOGIN_TYPE",
>       APP_VERSION : "APP_VERSION",
>       HEIGHT : "HEIGHT",
>       IID : "IID",
>       LATEST_VERSION : "LATEST_VERSION",
>       LOGIN_DISPLAY_TYPE : "LOGIN_DISPLAY_TYPE",
>       LOGIN_REALM : "LOGIN_REALM",
>       MAIN_FILE_PATH : "MAIN_FILE_PATH",
>       SHOW_IN_TASKBAR : "SHOW_IN_TASKBAR",
>       THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_URL : "THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_URL",
>       WELCOME_PAGE_URL : "WELCOME_PAGE_URL",
>       WIDTH : "WIDTH",
>       WORKLIGHT_ROOT_URL : "WORKLIGHT_ROOT_URL",
>       APP_SERVICES_URL : "APP_SERVICES_URL",
>       WLCLIENT_TIMEOUT_IN_MILLIS : "WLCLIENT_TIMEOUT_IN_MILLIS" };

// Short alias:
WL.AppProp = WL.AppProperty;

Getting error at below line :

> var reachabilityUrl =
>   WL.Client.getAppProperty(WL.AppProp.APP_SERVICES_URL) + "reach";

Comment: Why don't you first explain what are you trying to do or touch this part of your code. You probably shouldn't. Explain your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no such thing as `WL.AppProp`
2. There is no such property `APP_SERVICES_URL` available.

For available properties and correct API usage see the documentation for [getAppProperty](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.Client.html%23getAppProperty).